# MERN+ Cloudinary: Unsupported source URL

Tags: reactjs, express, axios, cloudinary

I'm trying to upload file to [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/). Here is part of my **react component**

```
...
addItem() {
    ...
    let file = this.fileInput.value;
    keywords !== "" && this.props.onAddItem(keywords, place, image);
    ...
  }
  render() {
    return (
      ....
      <Input
      type="file"
      innerRef={(input) => {this.fileInput = input}}
      name="image"
      id="image"
      placeholder=""/>
    )
  }
```

Here is **action file**:

```
export function onAddItem(keywords, place, file, id, isChangebale = false) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.all([
      axios.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/myservername/image/upload',
        {upload_preset: "mypresetname", file: file}),
      axios.post('http://localhost:3001/api/items/', { keywords, place, id, isChangebale })
    ])
    .then(axios.spread((cloudinaryRes, localRes) => {
      console.log(cloudinaryRes, localRes);
    }))
```

I receive error `xhr.js:178 POST https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/testovich/image/upload 400 (Bad Request)` and in response headers `"X-Cld-Error: Unsupported source URL: C:\fakepath\2017-12-07_19-06-445.png"`

When I test using [postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) I have correct response.

[image]

So it looks like I do something wrong when pass file from rect component to action file. How to pass correct path/file to cloudinary?

Answer (score 2):

There were two mistakes:
1. in react component there should be

```
let file = this.fileInput.files[0];//I upload only one file
```

instead of

```
let file = this.fileInput.value;
```

2. in action file

   export function onAddItem(keywords, place, image, id, isChangebale = false) {
     const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append("file", image);
     formData.append("upload_preset", "mypresetname");

   return (dispatch) => {
       axios.all([
         // AJAX upload request using Axios )
         axios.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/myservername/image/upload',
           formData,

instead of:

```
export function onAddItem(keywords, place, file, id, isChangebale = false) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios.all([
      axios.post('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/myservername/image/upload',
        {upload_preset: "mypresetname", file: file}),
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image to a base64 like `const base64Img = data:image/jpg;base64,${file.data};` 
The `file.data` represents the data property from response from image picker. 
Then I passed the base64Img to data like
 `return RNFetchBlob.fetch('POST', apiUrl, headerProps, [ { name: 'file', fileName: file.fileName, type: file.type, data: base64Img } ]);`
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was using formik and React and had the same Issue.
I was trying to upload a single image
After doing my research I realized there may be 2 possible causes of this error

1. The value you are passing to the formData must be a single File Object.

   const   upload= (file)=>{
   const data = new FormData();
   data. Append('file',file)
   data.append'cloud_name',<cloud_name>)
   data.append('upload_preset',<cloud_preset>)
   fetch('https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1//image/upload',
   {method:'post',body: data, mode:'cors'}).then(res=>
   res.json()).then(data=>{
   console.log(data)
   })

file here should be gotten from e.target.files[0] providing the correct index

```
<input type="file" name="file"  onChange={(e)=>{setFieldValue('image',e.target.files[0])}}/>
```

1. If the error still persists destructure the file value you are receiving from the form.

   ```
       onSubmit:(file)=>{ 
       const {image}= file

       upload(image)
   }
   ```